# add variable in query

Tags: php

i have this variable here:

```
$prefix=$wpdb->base_prefix  ;
```

Which prints

```
wp_
```

Now, i do have this query, and i need to insert it something like this:

```
$path = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $prefixbckg
 WHERE id = 1");
```

My output has to be this:

```
$path = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_bckg
 WHERE id = 1");
```

How can i do this? Because i need to make the prefix to be flexible, so i need to add the prefix before, without pre-defining it.
Thanks

Comment: `$path = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$prefix}bckg
 WHERE id = 1");` ?..

Answer (score 2):

The proper way:

```
$path = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM '.$prefix.'bckg WHERE id = 1');
```

The "I'm new to PHP" way:

```
$path = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$prefix}bckg WHERE id = 1");
```

Comment: Why is option number one more 'proper' than the second?

Comment: You mean... 'The way I like it' and 'The way it should be done' http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

Comment: @JonahBishop Because it uses single quotation marks so the parser won't waste time in searching for variable inside the statement... Whenever gets to the double quotations the php parser check whole statement for possible variable while with single it doesn't ... It is faster anyway...

Comment: It's faster, easier to read, editors can help you and it's the way that most languages do it.

Comment: While it may technically be faster, I can't believe it matters in 99.9% of cases. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these methods:

```
$prefix=$wpdb->base_prefix;
$mainPrefix = $prefix . 'bckg';
$path = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $mainPrefix WHERE id = 1");
```

or

```
$path = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$prefix}bckg WHERE id = 1");
```

Both results are same:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_bckg WHERE id = 1
```

But which one is faster!? I made a simple benchmark program and here is the sequel:

> The first method time is: 0.0608940124512
>
> The second method time is: 0.0609350204468

So the first method a bit faster than the second method :-)

Good Luck